# When to use numpy arrays vs scipy matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I read that numpy arrays are very good for tasks that allow for vectorization, but I also read that scipy matrices are very efficient for matrix manipulations. Given that numpy arrays seem to be more often associated with containing data, would it be better to use numpy arrays for creation and storage, but to convert to scipy matrices when heavy use of matrix operations are used?

In general what is the best practice for when to use numpy over scipy?

Comment: What do you mean scipy matrices? Sparse matrices? Or are you talking about numpy matrices

Comment: The only "scipy matrices" are the sparse matrices from the subpackage `scipy.sparse`.  If you are talking about `scipy.array`, that is exactly the same object as `numpy.array`.  The `scipy` namespace imports the names from `numpy`.  I think many scipy developers now realize that that was probably an API design mistake, but it's a hard one to undo.  I recommend always using the `numpy` namespace for `numpy` objects.

Comment: Oh word well that cleared that up. Use np as much as possible unless dealing with sparse matrices or anything that scipy handles of that nature